# Why self-terminating vm instances in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud Platform in Trial mode.

I have problem with Google Compute Engine VM instances.

Sometimes, for reasons beyond our control, our virtual machines spontaneously go offline. Google Cloud Monitoring records a change of state "running" to "terminated" for all three server projects, e.g.:

```
"4:02 AM Instance ****-application changed state running to terminated"
```

Nothing happens to the virtual machines after that, i.e., virtual machines remain offline, so they require manual start In order to continue their work.

Google Developers Console settings are set to the following:

> **Availability policies**
>
> - Preemptibility: Off (recommended)
> - Automatic restart: On (recommended)
> - On host maintenance: Migrate VM instance (recommended)

Maybe our virtual machines fall under the area restriction described in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#plannedterminate):

> **Why was my instance terminated with status "Planned termination by system"?**
>
> A "Planned termination by system" status means that your instance lived in a zone that was scheduled for maintenance and has been terminated since that maintenance window went into effect. "

But then [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#schedulingoptions) says that:

> By default, Google Compute Engine automatically manages the scheduling decisions for your instances. For example, if your instance is terminated due to a system or hardware failure, Compute Engine automatically restarts that instance. Instance scheduling options let you change this automatic behavior.

Comment: On the Developers Console check: 1. Output of the VMs serial console output for any errors or shutdown reasons. 2. Operations log and status message of the event. 
Also you can take a look into log files of your VM instances to see if any reason for shutdown can be found. Post it here, I'll try to figure out the issue.

Comment: this repeat on in Trial mode. this problem solving.